# Error unarchiving NSAttributedString on iOS13 with NSKeyedUnarchiver when NSTextAttachment is used

Tags: ios, ios13, nsattributedstring, ios14, nssecurecoding

I archive an `NSAttributedString`, which contains an image with `NSTextAttachment` on iOS14 and noticed, that unarchiving it on iOS13 fail. On iOS14 the unarchive is successful.

The error logged is this:

```
Error decoding string object. error=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4864 
"value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSTextAttachment'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSGlyphInfo,
    UIColor,
    NSURL,
    UIFont,
    NSParagraphStyle,
    NSString,
    NSAttributedString,
    NSArray,
    NSNumber,
    NSDictionary
)}'." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=value for key 'NS.objects' was of unexpected class 'NSTextAttachment'. Allowed classes are '{(
    NSGlyphInfo,
    UIColor,
    NSURL,
    UIFont,
    NSParagraphStyle,
    NSString,
    NSAttributedString,
    NSArray,
    NSNumber,
    NSDictionary
)}'.}
```

Is there an option to make that work, or am I doomed here?

This is how the image is inserted into an `NSMutableAttributedString` using `NSTextAttachment`:

```
// Add an image:
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = image;
NSMutableAttributedString *strWithImage = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment] mutableCopy];

[s appendAttributedString:strWithImage];
```

This is the archiving line:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:str requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];
```

This is the unarchiving line, which returns an `NSError` instance:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSAttributedString *str = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:NSAttributedString.class fromData:data error:&error];
```

I create the `NSData` instance on iOS14, store it to a file and read it in iOS13. This is when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says that `NSTextAttachment` can not be decoded becuase it is not in the list of classes those are supported.

You have to find a workaround to make it work on iOS 13 or lower.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

1. Remove all attachments from the `NSMutableAttributedString` instance.
2. `archive` it the same way that you are doing today.
3. Encode and store the `[TextAttachmentInfo]` JSON data paired with above data.
4. `unarchive` it the same way that you are doing today.
5. Decode the paired JSON data as `[TextAttachmentInfo]`.
6. Insert `NSTextAttachment`s into the unarchived `NSMutableAttributedString` instance

Here's some helper code that needs to be tuned and tested further according to your own use case.

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString {
    
    struct TextAttachmentInfo: Codable {
        let location: Int
        let imageData: Data
    }
    
    func removeAllTextAttachments() -> [TextAttachmentInfo] {
        guard self.length > 0 else { return [] }
        
        var textAttachmentInfos: [TextAttachmentInfo] = []
        
        for location in (0..<self.length).reversed() {
            var effectiveRange = NSRange()
            let attributes = self.attributes(at: location, effectiveRange: &effectiveRange)
            
            for (_, value) in attributes {
                if let textAttachment = value as? NSTextAttachment,
                   let data = textAttachment.image?.pngData() {
                    self.replaceCharacters(in: effectiveRange, with: "")
                    textAttachmentInfos.append(.init(location: effectiveRange.location, imageData: data))
                }
            }
        }
        
        return textAttachmentInfos.reversed()
    }
    
    func insertTextAttachmentInfos(_ infos: [TextAttachmentInfo]) {
        for info in infos {
            let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
            attachment.image = UIImage(data: info.imageData)
            self.insert(NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment), at: info.location)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I can see that from the error description already. Do you have a hint for a workaround?

Comment: @RainerSchwarze I added a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for me was to provide a list of acceptable classes in the `initWithCoder:` method of the class which contains the `NSAttributedString`. (Credits go to a solution from Markus Spoettl in the cocoa-dev mailing list from a couple of years ago.)

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSAttributedString *str = nil;
        // This fails on iOS13:
        // str = [coder decodeObjectOfClass:NSAttributedString.class forKey:@"attrStr"];

        // Provide a set of classes to make NSTextAttachment accepted:
        str = [coder decodeObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithObjects:
            NSAttributedString.class, 
            NSTextAttachment.class, nil] forKey:@"attrStr"];
        self.attrStr = str;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This seems to be an issue with other classes used with `NSAttributedString` too like `NSTextTab` etc. so depending on the use case, one can extend the list of acceptable classes.